# Store blog posts in a json file

Tags: json, blogs

I am thinking of putting my post data for my blog in a json file. Is this a good solution? Can I store html in it so it will render? Or am I just signing up for a nightmare? Thanks

Comment: Maybe look at something like [Kirby](http://getkirby.com/) as a file based CMS or [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) as a static site generator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  [Here](http://www.thorntech.com/2012/07/4-things-you-must-do-when-putting-html-in-json/) is a link showing some of the thing you'll have to deal with.

I would recommend doing this via an SQL database as it will be quite a bit faster (and possibly easier), but using json is a completely doable solution (although not quite the recommended.)

Comment: the problem with SQL is then I need to use something like PHP

Comment: @jrock2004 Yes, but you will have to do that if you use json too.  You can't store any blog data on your server without a server-side language like PHP.